# Azure Cloud Service - Access Denied (port bind)

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I am using Visual Studio 2013 to Publish a WorkerRole to Azure. The WorkerRole should bind on port 80, and start an Owin WebApp:

```
WebApp.Start<Startup>(new StartOptions(url: baseUri));
```

Everything works if I run it locally on the Azure Emulator, but when I run it live on Azure it fails. The relevant Exception is:

```
Inner Exception: Access is denied
   at System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes()
   at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinHttpListener.Start(HttpListener listener, Func`2 appFunc, IList`1 addresses, IDictionary`2 capabilities, Func`2 loggerFactory)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinServerFactory.Create(Func`2 app, IDictionary`2 properties)
```

I tried RDP-ing to the instance and adding the ACL rules which were the usual source of such errors on the local machine

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:80/ user=Everyone
```

but unsuccessfully, it still gives the same error.

Has anybody met with this issue and could point me to the right direction for solving it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I was binding to "*:80" instead of getting the URI properly from the configuration. So the proper way to get the baseUri to bind on for an Azure Worker is:

```
var endpoint = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["Endpoint1"];
string baseUri = String.Format("{0}://{1}", endpoint.Protocol, endpoint.IPEndpoint);
```

and then just bind:

```
WebApp.Start<Startup>(new StartOptions(url: baseUri));
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all it is strange to use WorkerRole with 80 binding while the WebRole available with the 80 port opened up.

Next. It seems that you have not defined input endpoint for the WorkerRole and the Azure firewall closes all ports. So to open the 80 port up try specifying an input endpoint in your `ServiceDefinition.csdef` file or at WorkerRole properties window, "Endpoints" tab. While publishing to the Azure it should hook up this configuration to open up the port.

So in short try updating your `ServiceDefinition.csdef` with this:

```
<ServiceDefinition name="MyService" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition">
  <WorkerRole name="WorkerRole1">    
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="HttpIn" protocol="http" port="80" localPort="80" />
    </Endpoints>
  </WorkerRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

Also check out these docs: [Enable Communication for Role Instances in Azure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/hh180158.aspx), [WorkerRole Schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg557552.aspx), [How to Configure Cloud Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-configure/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for useful pointers. I forgot to mention in my post that I've defined an Endpoint. But the problem turned out to be not to use the Endpoint URI to bind, but rather a separate configuration (as described in my answer).

Comment: But what do you mean by "WorkerRole with 80 binding while the WebRole available with the 80 port opened up"? I don't have a WebRole, or is there a default one?

Comment: I thought you can use WebRole and it should has the 80 port opened.